# Java print specific data from file

Tags: java, eclipse, substring, reader

I've a txt file. In there are rules and I have to get everything between the brackets in a separate file. But I don't even get it shown in the console.

I already tried many methods, but i always get some errors.(outlined code)

With the solution right now, it just showing nothing in the console. Does anyone know why?

The brackets are always in the same line as "InputParameters" i tried something with that, at the end of the code.

The solutions that are outlined won't work. Maybe someone got an idea?

with that code below i get the following error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -1     at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown
>   Source)   at blabla.execute.main(execute.java:17)

here some content from the txt file:

```
dialect  "mvel"   
rule "xxx"  
    when
        InputParameters (xy <= 1.124214, xyz <= 4.214214, abc <= 1.12421, khg <= 1.21421)   
    then


Ty
```

Here is the code:

```
public class execute {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;


        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:..."));

            java.lang.String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf(("\\("), line.indexOf(("\\)")))));

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Please remove the code sections that you do not use. Please also show us a small sample of the input you want to read.

Comment: It would be nice to see the text file along with a minimal code example.

Comment: @PhillipS "I just changed the while condition, and ...." -- add that info to your question

Comment: Please don't put code into comments, please [edit] your question.

Comment: edited my question with new code, an error and some content from txt file

Answer (score 0):

the problem is if you want to get the index of a string (indexOf()) in a string in which the searched string doesnt exist, indexOf returns -1 and if the method substring receives the argument -1 then it throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I suggest to check first if a line contains "InputParameter" since you said this word is always in the same line and then you get the string inside the brackets by using the methods subtring and indexOf.

this one works for me

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String filename = "$insertPathToFile$"; 
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null){
               if (line.contains("InputParameters")) {
                   System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf("(")+1, line.indexOf(")")));
               } // end if
               line = br.readLine();
            } // end while
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        } // end try
    } // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. That helped me out. But i won't close this Questions for now, because i can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -1 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown
>   Source) at blabla.execute.main(execute.java:17)

This exception means that `-1` was passed to `substring()` method. This `-1` is produced by `indexOf()` when it doesn't find anything.

Does all your lines contain brackets? There should be check if the brackets are present in the line.

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.indexOf(("\\(") != -1 && line.indexOf(("\\)") != -1) {
            System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf(("\\("), line.indexOf(("\\)")))));
        }
    }
```